# libgdx freetype dependency with maven archtype

Tags: java, maven, libgdx

I'm transitioning to maven for my libgdx project using [these instructions](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-maven-archetype). But my project requires freetype and I'm confused about how to add the dependency for it:

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: libgdx-freetype64.so
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:119)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:231)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:108)
    ... 7 more
```

Here's my desktop/pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.autonomousgames.starcycle</groupId>
    <artifactId>starcycle-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-freetype-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-freetype</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-backend-lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
    <classifier>natives-desktop</classifier>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: And when I run "mvn clean install -Pdesktop" I get the following:

```
main:
     [java] Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     [java]     at com.autonomousgames.starcycle.core.screens.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:20)
     [java]     at com.autonomousgames.starcycle.core.StarCycle.create(StarCycle.java:40)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
     [java] Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx-freetype64.so' for target: Linux, 64-bit
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:110)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType.initFreeType(FreeType.java:541)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.<init>(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:101)
     [java]     at com.autonomousgames.starcycle.core.Texturez.<clinit>(Texturez.java:261)
     [java]     ... 4 more
     [java] Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: libgdx-freetype64.so
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:119)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:231)
     [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:108)
     [java]     ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add classifiers to any platform-specific jars, noted by the inclusion of the word platform:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-freetype-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
    <classifier>natives-desktop</classifier>  ### Here
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-backend-lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
    <classifier>natives-desktop</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This resolved an issue I was having as well. The error I was getting was "Couldn't load shared library 'gdx64.dll' for target". I added the classifier to my `gdx-platform` dependency and it worked. Did you find some documentation explaining how this works?